# Drop down menu in ROR with integer options not String

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to create a drop down menu in rails having integer options I want to create a drop down menu for year say 2000 to 2013, but the option selected from the menu should be stored in the database as integer not as a String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by taking the menu item and converting to an integer before saving.

menu_item.to_i